# Check expected URL and display the actual URL

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, gherkin

In a functional test, I am trying to write a "Then" step where I check the current URL.

After looking on SO, it seems that the right way to do it is to "wait" that the url becomes the expected one :

```
Then('The URL contains {string}', function(url, callback) {
  browser.wait(EC.urlContains(url), 5000)
    .then(() => callback())
});
```

The problem is that if the condition is wrong, I don't know what is the actual URL and that would be helpful for debugging.

I tried to do the following :

```
Then('The URL contains {string}', function(url, callback) {
  browser.wait(EC.urlContains(url), 5000)
    .then(() => callback())
    .catch(() => { throw Error('URL was ' + location.href); });
});
```

but I get an error because `location` is `undefined`.

I also tried the following :

```
Then('The URL contains {string}', function(url, callback) {
  browser.wait(EC.urlContains(url), 5000)
    .then(() => callback())
    .catch(() => { throw Error('URL was ' + browser.executeScript('location.href')); });
});
```

But I can only see :

> Error: URL was ManagedPromise::19695 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}

Because `browser.executeScript` only returns a `Promise`.

What is the right way to display the actual URL in the error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it :

```
Then('The URL contains {string}', function (url, callback) {
  browser.wait(EC.urlContains(url), 5000)
    .then(() => callback())
    .catch(() => {
      browser.getCurrentUrl().then((url) => { throw Error('URL was ' + url); });
    });
});
```